# Sync notes between Android phone and Ubuntu?

Tags: android, sync

I want a note taking app on my Ubuntu running laptop and an app on my Android phone which can sync with each other, through online means or manually syncing. So far the only thing I've seen is the Evernote app for android and the beta quality third party app [Nevernote](http://nevernote.sourceforge.net/).
Ideally, I'd like an app that syncs with Tomboy, but the only thing I've found is Tomdroid which is buggy and only lets you view notes.

Does anyone have any suggestions? Or will I have to stick to Android apps which only sync with web sites?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an app for Android called [Tomdroid](https://launchpad.net/tomdroid) which had experimental support for web syncing and seems to be close to making a new release. See [this thread](https://lists.launchpad.net/tomdroid-dev/msg00142.html) on the tomdroid mailing list.

Comment: canonical should fund tomdroid to sync to ubuntu one and android :)

Answer (score 4):

I just use text files in a Dropbox folder, in conjunction with Dropbox clients on "real" computers and the Android Dropbox App on my phone. Simple, but it works really well. And if you need something more sophisticated, using .doc files and .xls files with OpenOffice (on the PCs) and DocumentsToGo (on the phone) also works very well (DocumentsToGo is the only Android app I've paid money for, but there's nothing free to compare with it).

Answer (score 1):

There is an Ubuntu One client for Android. It seems like you should be able to sync any files from your phone to your desktop.

If Ubuntu One can't do it, DropBox can.

Comment: Right but the Ubuntu One android application is for syncing contacts and (currently) doesn't sync Tomboy notes.

Comment: What's the name of the client? I can't find it on the marketplace.

Answer (score 1):

It's web-based, but 'GooMemo' will sync with a Google Docs account, which in turn could be accessed from or potentially sync'd with Ubuntu.  That's what I'm using at the moment.

That said, all of my notes on my ubuntu machine are in a hierarchical tree managed by 'pytombo' (since before I had an android phone).  Unfortunately I've not found an equivalent on android to allow me to browse/change these files other than a simple file manager.

Hope that helps and I'll read the other answers with interest!

Answer (score 1):

YES, it's possible without any CLouds.

Even in 2020 it's a "problem" to sync Android notes, adresses, dates etc with Ubuntu without using any clouds, especially US-american data gathering clouds.

Here's what I did (basement is UBUNTU 18.04 and Samsung S7):

Install CompanionLink on Android cellphone (free)
Install CompanionLink via WINE (because it's Windows Software) on Ubuntu 
  (you need to pay a little fee for the Windows version of CompanionLink)
Install an old MS-Office Pro 2007 also via WINE on Ubuntu

Create the same User  (like your mailbox on Android) in MS-Office
 fill it with at least one contact, date, note, task.
Start CompanionLink and adjust the type sync-method you prefer
(wifi, usb or companion-cloud) 
Hint: I onyl use direct way via WIFI because I never use anykind of clouds to keep my data private.

First sync should be ANDROID to Outlook no deletions at all!!!!

When this is done, you may create new items in each of them.
According to your subsequent adjustments how to sync, it will sync all latest updates visversa. (simply learn all options CompanioLink provides)

So, be happy or die in the linux-jungle  ;o))
[just see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g0gVc.jpg)

Comment: No Google-, no Samsung-, no Microsoft-Cloud is required!    This solution provides a direct sync between ANDROID and an Ubuntu system.

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly use notes. I use task with notes attached.

I use [RememberTheMilk](http://://www.rememberthemilk.com), a web based task manager (you can attach any number of notes to a task). There are at least two apps that sync to it in Android (the official one only works with premium accounts). You can use Tasque to sync with it in ubuntu.

There are lots of other [ways](http://www.rememberthemilk.com/services/) to sync or read RtM. I even used a Google Desktop Widget to put my task on a sidebar (it wasn't really practical).

I know this is not a exactly what you asked, but as you haven't accepted any answer it could be a interesting workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I use Nitro for my notes, You can find it in the Ubuntu Software Centre. Set it up to sync via Ubuntu One or Dropbox, it is easy and works great. When I am on windows (work, ect) I use it in portable Chrome/Chromium from the web store, then set up my sync and I am good to go. For your android devices you can install NitroDroid from the Play store. It works great and now I have my notes with me wherever I am. It is easy and pain free, I highly suggest you try out Nitro on all three platforms it works great.

Answer (score 0):

I think Evernote is the best option if you want the best support on the go.

It has a full featured web version accessible from anywhere pretty much as well as the localised clients for all the popular phone OS, Nevernote support for Linux and Desktop Windows/Mac support.

So if you don't want to be withyour notes anywhere, I'd go with Evernote.

It is what I use and I've never had a problem with it so far.

Answer (score 0):

i am using fiinote and jotterpadx on android to make notes on android  and to sync the notes i further use dropsync in android which syncs selected folder to dropbox. by dropsync i am sharing the notes saved in the respective folder of jotterpadx and fiinote . however we need to export the notes made in fiinote in pdf or txt in order to be able to open in ubuntu desktop

- fiinote : https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fiistudio.fiinote
- jotterpadx : https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jotterpad.x
- dropsync : https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ttxapps.dropsync